# How to symplify a linear congruence?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How do we simplyfy a linear congruence such as `30u + 26 ≡ 3 (mod 7)` to such `u ≡ 6 (mod 7)` . ?

Comment: Reduce everything modulo $7$, isolate the term involving $u$, and multiply by $2^{-1}$.

Comment: You can treat congruences largely like equations - you can add the same thing to both sides, subtract, multiply, **but** you cannot divide, and you can cancel only in limited circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, cast out 7s on each side so the congruence becomes easier to manage:

$30u+26\equiv3$ mod 7

$2u-2\equiv3$ mod 7  (As 28 = 4 X 7)

$2u\equiv5$ mod 7   (Add 2 to each side)

$8u\equiv20$ mod 7  (Multiplying both sides by 4)

$u\equiv6$ mod 7 (As I cast out 7 on the left side, and the right 14 = 2 X 7)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ {\rm mod}\ 7\!:\,\ \color{#c00}0\equiv 30u+23\equiv 2u+2\equiv \color{#c00}{2(u+1)}\,\Rightarrow\, u\equiv\,\ldots\,$ since $\,\color{#c00}7\mid \color{#c00}{2n}\,\Rightarrow\,7\mid n,\,$ by $\,\ldots$