# Solving Linear congruences

Tags: number-theory

My question is-:

$30 u +26 \equiv 3 \left(mod \, \, \, 7\right )$

I was stuck solving this.As usual i took help from this site and found the solution

[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/667049/how-to-symplify-a-linear-congruence)

But i am not following how

$30u+26\equiv 3 \left(mod \, \, \, 7 \right)  $

into
$2u-2\equiv3$ mod 7  (As 28 = 4 X 7)

It would be helpful if anyone help me how this conversion is done.

If anyone have any other idea of solving this .please share it

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked question and the second time you wrote it you have the congruence $30u+26\equiv 3\pmod{7}$ but the first time you wrote it it was $30u+26\equiv 6\pmod{7}$.  Since I already wrote it out as though it was congruent to three, I will leave it as is since that seems to be the intended.  The steps are essentially the same if you were to have started with $6$ instead though, just a small bit of difference in how you break the terms up.

$\begin{array}{rlr}30u+26\equiv& 3\pmod{7}\\
30u+23\equiv&0\pmod{7}&\text{by subtracting 3 from each side}\\
28u+2u + 21+2\equiv &0\pmod{7}&\text{by breaking apart some terms on the left}\\
7\cdot 4u + 2u + 7\cdot 3+2\equiv &0\pmod{7}&\text{by rewriting those terms broken off as multiples of seven}\\
0+2u+0+2\equiv &0\pmod{7}&\text{since multiples of seven are equivalent to zero mod7}\\
2u\equiv &-2\pmod{7}&\text{simplifying and subtracting two from each side}\\
u\equiv &-1\pmod{7}&\text{by "division by two"}(\dagger)\\
u+7\equiv &6\pmod{7}&\text{by adding 7 to each side}\\
u\equiv &6\pmod{7}&\text{since multiples of seven are equivalent to zero mod7}
\end{array}$

Note that the step labeled $(\dagger)$ is allowed here since $2$ has a multiplicative inverse modulo $7$ (*we know this since $\gcd(2,7)=1$*), so the step could have been rephrased as "multiplication by four" since $4$ is $2$'s multiplicative inverse.

---

With enough practice, one doesn't need to take nearly as many steps in simplifying modular equations, opting to just replace terms with things they are equivalent to in a single step., e.g. $30\equiv 2\pmod{7}$ so $30u\equiv 2u\pmod{7}$.  Similarly $26\equiv -2\pmod{7}$ giving us the immediate result $30u+26\equiv 2u-2\pmod{7}$, and since congruency is an equivalence relation $2u-2\equiv 3\pmod{7}$ by transitivity.

Comment: @:JMoravitz ,i corrected my question. I have doubt in your last step  i.e "by adding 7 to each side " LHS still  remains u ,why not u+7?

Comment: @laura because $7\equiv 0\pmod{7}$.

Comment: @:JMoravitz,one more doubt: if we have linear congruence equation as : $42u\equiv 2\, \, mod \, \, 7 $ then cant we divide it both sides with 2 to get $21u\equiv 1\, \, mod \, \, 7 $  ? as GCD of $\left ( 42,7 \right )\neq 1 $

Comment: @laura it isn't a question about whether what you are *dividing* being coprime to the modulus, but rather what you are *dividing by* being coprime to the modulus. It really is better explained that 4 is the multiplicative inverse to 2 mod7 since 4 times 2 is congruent to 8 is congruent to 1 mod 7.

Comment: "Division" may have been a mistake to call it for you since you could have $2u \equiv 3\pmod7 $ implies $ u\equiv 2^{-1}\cdot 3\pmod7$ implies $ u\equiv 5 \pmod7 $. We don't literally divide, we don't say it is equivalent to 1.5, but if you *could* divide and it remain an integer and what you are dividing by is coprime to the modulus, then it works exactly how you'd hope

Comment: @:JMoravitz  to solve $u \equiv 2^{-1}\cdot 3\, \left ( mod\, \, 7 \right ) $ we need to solve $2^{-1}$ .is this $2^{-1}$ multiplicative inverse of $2$ mod $7$ , am confused because i am using Bézout coefficients to find the multiplicative inverse in the form of **$s\cdot a \equiv 1 \left ( mod\, \, m \right )$** then $s$ is multiplicative inverse of $a$ mod $m$

Comment: You can find inverses by inspection, in this case 2 times 4 is 8 which is 7+1 which is equivalent to 1, or another easy method is via the euclidean algorithm

Comment: using Euclidean algorithm $7=3*2+1\Rightarrow 2=1*2+0\Rightarrow 1=1*7-2*3\Rightarrow \text{-3 is the inverse of } 2\, \, mod\, \, 7$  please help me out in this doubt ..i will not disturb you furthur ,thanks

Comment: -3 is correct too.  Note -3+7=4 so -3 is equivalent to 4 mod7

Comment: okk thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

Remember that
$$(x+y) \operatorname{mod} n = x \operatorname{mod} n + y \operatorname{mod} n$$
$$(xy) \operatorname{mod} n = x \operatorname{mod} n \cdot y \operatorname{mod} n $$
So
$$30 u + 26 \operatorname{mod} 7 = 30u \operatorname{mod} 7 + 26 \operatorname{mod} 7 =30 \operatorname{mod} 7\cdot u \operatorname{mod} 7 +(-2) \operatorname{mod} 7 = $$
$$ 2 \operatorname{mod} 7 \cdot u \operatorname{mod} 7 + (-2) \operatorname{mod} 7 = 2u \operatorname{mod} 7 + (-2) \operatorname{mod} 7 = (2u-2) \operatorname{mod} 7$$

Answer (score 1):

Well, we know that if $a \equiv b \ (m)$, then $c\cdot a \equiv c\cdot b \ (m)$ and $a +d \equiv b + d \ (m)$, so

$$
30u + 26 \equiv 6 (7) \\
30u \equiv -20 \ (7) \\
30u \equiv 1 \ (7) \\
$$

Now since $30 \equiv 2 \ (7)$,

$$
2u \equiv 1 \ (7)
$$

and because 2 is coprime with 7, there must be an inverse of 2, modulo 7. We can see that $2 \cdot 4 \equiv 1 \ (7)$ and therefore, multiplying both sides of the previous equivalence by 4 leaves us with

$$
u \equiv 4 \ (7)
$$