# Solve $30u+26 \equiv 3\, \mod 7$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

### Question

> Solve $30u+26 \equiv 3\,\mod 7$

I know the solution is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/667049/how-to-symplify-a-linear-congruence),but i want to know what is flaw in my approach.

### My Approach

> $30u+26 \equiv 3\, \mod 7$
>
> $30u \equiv -23\,\mod 7$
>
> $u \equiv -23\times30^{-1}\, \mod 7 \tag{1}$

let's us find $30^{-1}\, \mod 7$

> $30=7\times4+2$
>
> $7=2\times3+1$
>
> $1=7-2\times3$
>
> $1=7-3\times(30-7\times4)$
>
> $1=13\times7-3\times30-$

$30^{-1}\,\mod 7=3$

putting the value of $30^{-1}\,\mod 7$ in $(1)$,

> $u \equiv -23\times3\, \mod 7$
>
> $u \equiv -69\,\mod 7=1$
> but answer is $6$.  Where am I wrong?

Comment: Note that the inverse of $30$ is not $3$, but  rather $-3$ from what you have written, since $30 \times -3 \equiv  1 \mod 7$ from above.

Comment: I believe just the last step. -69 mod 7 = -1 mod 7 = 6

Comment: @Matteo: $-69 \equiv 1 \bmod 7$; the difference between the two sides is 70.

Comment: @Hurkyl. Thanks for the correction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

value of $30^{-1}\text{mod} \,7=-3$ which i have written $3$.

Hence putting the value of $30^{-1}\text{mod}\, 7$  in $(1)$,

$u \equiv -23*(-3) \text{mod}\,7$

> $u \equiv 69 \text{mod}\,7=6$

Comment: Yes, that was the correction to be made.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг thnak you :)

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг my steps are alright .?

Comment: Yes, your steps are absolutely fine.

Answer (score 1):

$$30n+26-3\equiv2n+2\equiv2(n+1).$$
Thus, $$n\equiv-1(\operatorname{mod}7)$$ or
$$n\equiv6(\operatorname{mod}7)$$

Comment: @laura You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

When you want to solve a linear modulo n problem, say to yourself two things:

$\quad$ I can't stand seeing negative signs.
$\quad$ I can't stand seeing numbers $\ge n$.

A chain of equivalent equations:

$30u+26 \equiv 3\, \mod 7$
$2u+5 \equiv 3\, \mod 7$
$2u \equiv 3 -5\, \mod 7$
$2u \equiv -2\, \mod 7$
$2u \equiv 5\, \mod 7$
$u \equiv (2^{-1}) (5)\, \mod 7$
$u \equiv (4) (5)\, \mod 7$
$u \equiv 20\, \mod 7$
$u \equiv 6\, \mod 7$

Comment: I think this is helpful step-by-step advise a student can follow. I guess a real smart 'professor' downvoted without a comment.  So sad...

Comment: The question included a link to such an approach and specifically asked not for a solution but for what's wrong with their approach.

Comment: @bdn i put out my answer when all the dust had settled. If you notice laura answered her own question. Thanks for responding - feedback helps!

Comment: @bdn I don't always check out all links/details after time elapse.